# How to mimic the Draw('same') from ROOT with matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, root-framework

I have a use case from ROOT that I have not been able to reproduce with matplotlib. Here is a minimal example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
dist1x = np.random.normal(5, 0.05, 10_000)  
dist1y = np.random.normal(5, 0.05, 10_000)
dist2x = np.random.normal(15, 0.05, 10_000)  
dist2y = np.random.normal(15, 0.05, 10_000)

ax.hist2d(dist1x, dist1y, bins=100, cmap='viridis')
ax.hist2d(dist2x, dist2y, bins=100, cmap='viridis')

plt.show()
```

and the output is

[image]

With ROOT one can do:

```
TCanvas *c1 = new TCanvas("c1","c1");

TH1D *h1 = new TH1D("h1","h1",500,-5,5);
h1->FillRandom("gaus");

TH1D *h2 = new TH1D("h2","h2",500,-5,5);
h2->FillRandom("gaus");

h1->Draw();
h2->Draw("SAME");
```

and the two histograms will share the canvas, axes, etc. Why plotting the two histograms in the same figure only shows the last one? How can I reproduce the ROOT behavior?

Comment: I suspect you may want to show the desired output, else it's really hard to imagine how two histograms on top of each other should look like.

Comment: You're completely right and it;s a fair point to bring this. The root example is not the best either. I also don't fully know what the ROOT behaviour is. @sauerburger answer was exactly what I was expecting to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think the intended behavior is to draw the sum of both histograms**. You can do this by concatenating the arrays before plotting:

```
ax.hist2d(np.concatenate([dist1x, dist2x]),
          np.concatenate([dist1y, dist2y]),
          bins=100, cmap='viridis')
```

[image: Matplotlib sum of histograms]

(I've modified the number a bit, to make sure the two blobs overlap.)

---

The default behavior in ROOT for `SAME` with `TH2F` is probably not desirable.

[image: ROOT SAME]

The second histogram is drawn **over** the other, overwriting the fill color of the bins. The information from the first histogram is discarded in every cell if there is at least one event from the second histogram.

To reproduce this behavior, I'd suggest to use `numpy.histogram2d`. Set the bins of the first histogram to zero if there are entries in the second one, and then plot the sum of both.

```
bins = np.linspace(0, 20, 100), np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
hist1, _, _ = np.histogram2d(dist1x, dist1y, bins=bins)
hist2, _, _ = np.histogram2d(dist2x, dist2y, bins=bins)
hist1[hist2 > 0] = 0
sum_hist = hist1 + hist2
plt.pcolormesh(*bins, sum_hist)
```

[image: Matplotlib "SAME"]

---

If the two histograms don't have any populated bin in common, the two behaviors are identical.